# react-router how to access this.props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

How can I access `this.props` from `<Router>`'s `onUpdate`? I need to be able to see what the current route is, I need to access `this.props.route` I think to determine what page it is (`name`). [image] I can't find some resource for it. I have my code like this (right now it checks window.location to determine what page it is but the problem is slug as it can be any different static page):

```
const logPageViews = () => {
  if (_.startsWith(window.location.pathname, '/search/')) {
    let query = window.location.pathname.replace('/search/', '').replace(/--/g, '/').replace(/-/g, '+');
    if (!_.isEmpty(window.location.search)) {
      query += `&${window.location.search.replace('?', '')}`;
    }

    ga.pageview(`/search?query=${query}`);
  } else {
    ga.pageview(window.location.href.replace(window.location.origin, ''));
  }

  fbq.pageView();
}

const reducer = combineReducers(reducers);
const store = applyMiddleware(...middlewares)(createStore)(reducer, initialState);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router routes={getRoutes(store)} history={browserHistory} onUpdate={() => {logPageViews()}} />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Comment: Does it help to call `logPageViews` directly instead of wrapping it in an anonymous function? So: `onUpdate={logPageViews}`

Comment: @MaartenBicknese `this` is still undefined when doing that.

Answer (score 0):

I have two possible answers. First, could you potentially access the current route from the state, like this demonstration here? https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/issues/1539

Second, when you call getRoutes(store), could you then access the last element of the array of routes?

Comment: For first: You mean https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/issues/1539#issuecomment-121499082 or https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/issues/1539#issuecomment-128403889 ? For first link, I don't know what `routerStateChange` is and `this` is undefined on my `onUpdate` function. On second link, I get `Invalid prop 'children' supplied to 'Provider', expected a single ReactElement.`

Comment: For second: What I did is `const allRoutes = getRoutes(store);` then I get an array of all my routes when I do `console.log(allRoutes);`